# Periodically site falls with error "Mysql connect error [localhost]: (2002) Connection refused (400)"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, bitrix

Site works on CMS Bitrix. Periodically, site falls with error Conection refused, after mysqld restart everything works. And it works 2-3 days, after falls again. I don't understand, what's the problem. Unfortunately, I don't have logs, cause that time logs weren't enabled, now I enabled logs, but site works perfectly 5 days. But I guess, error will be soon. Can I do anything without logs, maybe somebody faced such a problem and can suggest what to check. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a network or other hardware error.  Please provide the topology.

Answer (score 0):

Bitrix has pretty "heavy" sql queries. Maybe you are running out of memory limit.
Check Settings->Performance (I don't know if you are using russian version or else) in your admin panel.It can help you determine "heavy" queries or components. Also, check if Caching is enabled on your site. Sometimes caching is disabled during development stage and it needs to be enabled. It can realy lower your server load.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same error, can you please help on this ?